# What is a winning strategy in Ninstar - Second Floor

Tags: frozen-synapse

In the chapter called "Ninstar", I am stuck in the second mission, "Second Floor".

The green team starts in a small room in the middle of the map. There are (too) many openings in the walls to have the soldiers monitor the doors while being hidden in some corners of the room.

The red team overwhelms the green team before the 10-turn counter is finished. What is a winning strategy?

The green team is composed of:

- 2 Rocket launcher units
- 2 Shotgun units
- 1 Machine Gun unit

The red team is composed of:

- few Sniper units
- many Shotgun units
- many Machine Gun unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got updated in the latest patch so check you have the latest one. This level was notoriously difficult so they added a couple of people for you, but I can't remember how many total that was.

Watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&list=PL1C65777F1EF19C49&v=A7aDt9wbG2s) for ideas

Comment: I hope it is now more than five units. However, I have Steam, so my game should always be up-to-date, so I have low hope of getting an advantage with a patch.

Comment: Ah, yeah I'm about 75% sure that the update introduced two extra to make it into 5.

Comment: How come someone would be able to master this level with only 3 units?

Comment: @wok Honestly people had to

Comment: I did it by ducking a lot!